# Can't alter table add column on Mysql ndbcluster - errno: 851

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

I want to alter and add a new column to Mysql table which is ndbcluster:

```
ALTER TABLE `schema`.`table` 
ADD COLUMN `test` VARCHAR(255) NULL;
```

But it gives error:

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'my_table.#sql-1706_142' (errno: 851)
```

I don't have much experience with ndbcluster but as my research I come around that there are some limitations to the width of the table.
I've also read [this part in docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-database-objects.html) :

> In addition, the maximum offset for a fixed-width column of an NDB table is 8188 bytes; attempting to
> create a table that violates this limitation fails with NDB error 851 Maximum offset for fixed-size
> columns exceeded. For memory-based columns, you can work around this limitation by using a variable-
> width column type such as VARCHAR or defining the column as COLUMN_FORMAT=DYNAMIC; this does not work
> with columns stored on disk. For disk-based columns, you may be able to do so by reordering one or
> more of the table's disk-based columns such that the combined width of all but the disk-based column
> defined last in the CREATE TABLE statement used to create the table does not exceed 8188 bytes, less
> any possible rounding performed for some data types such as CHAR or VARCHAR; otherwise it is
> necessary to use memory-based storage for one or more of the offending column or columns instead.

My table and all columns storage type is DISK. But I really don't understand what should I do in order to increase the limitations.

I can set the storage type of my new column as MEMORY, It works but It's not the option in my case because I don't want data to be lost after server crash.

Comment: You would need to show the statement that is raising this error.

Comment: It's just an ALTER query. I've updated the question

Comment: The length of one of my VARCHAR columns in the current table was 1024. So I've ended up decreasing it to 255. Then run the alter query and it worked. But still don't know how to increase the limit of table